# Button click not updating the angular formControlName value

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

I have a form that has <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> for incrementing the value and formControlName is not updated when I use those buttons but works when I input manually. How to get around this? The code is below:

```
<form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Amenities</ng-template>
      <h5>How many guests can your place accomodate?</h5>
      <p class="textClass">
        Please specify the nuamber of guests your place can easily accomodate
        comfortably.
      </p>
      <div class="def-number-input number-input safari_only">
        <button
          onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()"
          class="minus"
        ></button>
        <input
          formControlName = "guestCapacity"
          min="0"
          type="number"
        />
        <button
          onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()"
          class="plus"
        ></button>
      </div>
</form>
```

I console logged the value and also used subscriber to see if it changes but like I said before it only works when I type the input manually and the button does not have any effect.

```
submit() {
    console.log(this.secondFormGroup.controls.guestCapacity.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way of implementation should be:

1. In input tag we have put `#guestCapacity` template reference variable
2. In minus button, we access the `guestCapacity` formcontrol, and decrease the value by 1
3. In plus button, we access the `guestCapacity` formcontrol & template reference variable to increase the value by 1.

```
<form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Amenities</ng-template>
    <h5>How many guests can your place accomodate?</h5>
    <p class="textClass">
        Please specify the nuamber of guests your place can easily accomodate
        comfortably.
    </p>
    <div class="def-number-input number-input safari_only">

        <!-- Get the guestCapacity formcontrol and decrease the value by 1 -->
        <button (click)="secondFormGroup.get('guestCapacity').setValue(guestCapacity?.value - 1)"
            class="minus"></button>
        <input #guestCapacity formControlName="guestCapacity" min="0" type="number" />

        <!-- Get the guestCapacity formcontrol and increase the value by 1 -->
        <button (click)="secondFormGroup.get('guestCapacity').setValue(guestCapacity?.value + 1)" class="plus"></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure about the query selector, and If it actually works, but let me give you a different approach.

If you want to reference a node in angular you can use `#` or `ref`, like this,

```
<button
  onclick="guestCapacity.stepDown()"
  class="minus"
></button>
<input #guestCapacity
  formControlName = "guestCapacity"
  min="0"
  type="number"
/>
<button
  onclick="guestCapacity.stepUp()"
  class="plus"
></button>
```

Comment: I tried this but did not work the way I wanted it to.